# How to add a map that website's users can add a pin to

Tags: html

I'm developing a website, and I would like there to be a single map that all users can pin a location on. All users should be able to see all other users' pinned location(s). I do not have a map yet.

What are some potential ways of accomplishing this? Is there some API that I can use? If so, I would prefer to use a free one (for now, at least). If such an API does not exist, I'd be okay with an API that will cost me.

If there is any important information that you need to be able to help me, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use google maps for this.
Here have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htk42n08/)

On each mouse click, you can save the latitude and longitude in the DB and also plot a new marker on the map.

First, create the map using:

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 4,
       center: myLatlng
  });
```

Then for each latitude and longitude stored in the DB, create a marker.

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
  });
```

For each map click event, add a marker on the map and save the location in DB.

```
map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    myLatlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
    // Save myLatlng in DB
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map
      })
  });
```

You can have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) for more about map events

Answer (score 0):

Use mapping tools like Google or bing. They all have pretty extensive apis.

Get users latitude/longitude when they pin a location and store it in a database. Pull all stored coordinations when you initialize your map and then simply display them on the map.

Comment: Any specific examples of APIs that can be used?

Comment: check google mapping api. It has mapping, distance, geolocation and a bunch of mapping apis. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro